# AsyncTask called a lot from many places

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I'm using a simple AsyncTask to download the sourcecode of a web page as a String. So far everything works fine.

However, I don't want to always do the same thing with the result String, sometimes I want to fill the gui with it, sometimes I want to parse it, sometimes I want to call more functions with it as a parameter.
Actually, I have more than one activity and more than one class that need to download the sourcecode of a page.

Of course, onPostExecute() is what has to handle the result of my Task, but since it will be called from so many places and for so many different reasons I'm really at a loss.

What can I do?

I really don't want to write 20 AsyncTasks that always do the same thing in their doInBackground(...) with different onPostExecute, nor I want the code from 20 different classes/activity to end up in a single onPostExecute, my code would be so complicated to maintain.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: why not create a public class to share the method to the other classes.

Comment: write a Custom AsyncTask-class overriding/implementing the existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would resolve it with the use of interfaces. Make an async task that does the right stuff in the doInBackground and that takes some parameter so that you know what to do in the onPostExecute and pass the parameter and result down to onPostExecute.

then make an interface with a method like **handleSourceCodeString(String source);** and then implement one class for every action that you want to do. Then put the classes in a map in some init function.

```
Map<String, Class> myActionMap = new HashMap<String,Class>;
myActionMap.put("parse-soruce", ParseSource.class) //(where ParseSource.class implements your interface)
```

and then in your postExecute do something like:

```
((MyActionInterface)myActionMap.get(action).newInstance()).handleSourceCodeString(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this... love the idea... seems pretty straight forward and better than using interfaces in my opinion.

[AsyncTask onPostExecute call from outside the AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429855/asynctask-onpostexecute-call-from-outside-the-asynctask)

Look at the first answer