# AsyncTask onPostExecute call from outside the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to use the same AsyncTask in different places on my App and I want a different **onPostExecute** for each one. It's possible to call them from **onCreate** method instead of from AsyncTask class?

Something like:

```
new AsyncTCP.execute()
onPostExecute(){
//DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create an `AsyncTask` with no `onPostExecute` method overridden

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Whatever, Whatever, Whatever> {

    @Override
    protected Whatever doInBackground(Whatever... whatever) {
        // whatever
        return whatever;
    }

}
```

And then when you want different implementations of `onPostExecute`, create anonymous task or descendant class and use it

```
task = new YourTask() {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExcecute(Whatever result) {
        //whatever
    }

};
task.execute();
```

Or better

```
public class YourTaskAnother extends YourTask {

    // just override onPostExecute here

    @Override
    protected void onPostExcecute(Whatever result) {
        //whatever
    }
}

task = new YourTaskAnother();
task.execute();
```

Comment: @user3779166 hey! please accept answers if they're helpful.

Comment: This is a great option (the first one). Seems less complex. I don't understand why they just didn't incorporate a way for us to pass in a callback function...that would minimize so many issues. We'd have one asynctask but many different handling options with the response.

Comment: @Carine they made this class as simple as needed, so it's not bloated with features. This is easy to implement so I don't see any issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add a switch case in the onPostExecute() method depending on all possible scenarios. Then inside the AyncTask add a constructor using which you could pass the type.

```
DownloadTask extends AsyncTask ...
{
    int postExecuteType; 
    public DownloadTask(int type) {
        this.postExecuteType = type; 
    }
...

    protected void onPostExecuted()
    {
        switch(type) {
            case 1:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Now just call `newDownloadTask(1).execute();`

Comment: You can, but it's too complex. I would prefer to override onPostExecute in subclasses.

Comment: Yep. I just realized after seeing your answer :-) Yours is easier and makes more sense.